# Is there an equivalent of "Ping_exporter" of prometheus to monitor windows targets

Tags: windows, prometheus, monitoring

I want to monitor the ping status of a windows system. Is there a windows specific version of ping_exporter ?
Or is there another better way to monitor windows target ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I solved my problem by using Multi target exporter (blackbox exporter)
It has ICMP module and the exporter can run on a different machine and can probe several targets with ICMP.